# Find global median from medians of subgroups

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics, median

Supposte I have a list of numbers $\{x_1, \ldots, x_N\}$, not necessarily ordered, and I divide it in subsets $\{ \{x_1,\ldots,x_{d_1}\}, \{x_{d_1+1},\ldots,x_{d_2}\}, \ldots \}$, where $d_n$ is the number of elements in each subset, then the mean over the entire set $\langle x\rangle$ is the weighted mean of the mean in each subset:

$$
\langle x \rangle = \sum_j \langle x_j\rangle \frac{d_j}{N}
$$

where $d_j$ is the number of elements in each subset and the sum is over the subsets. If I want to compute the median of the entire set and I know the median in each subset, does an analogous formula exists?

Comment: If you partition your original set into $\frac N 5$ sets with $5$ elements each and then take the median of medians then this may not be the overall median but will be a element between $30\%$ position and $70\%$ position in the original set (with minor adjustments if $N$ is not a multiple of $5$).  You can use this to create an $O(n)$  algorithm for finding the median of the original set

Comment: This is interesting but I didn't get it...why between 30% and 70%? And how to create the algorithm? Could you be more specific?

Comment: The median of medians in my example is greater than or equal to half the medians, so $\frac{N}{10}$ which in turn are greater than or equal to two other elements in their subsets, so the median of medians is greater than or equal to at least $\frac{3N}{10}$ elements i.e. $30 \%$ of them.  Similarly it is less than or equal to $30\%$ of the original elements.  You can read more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians

Answer (score 3):

It does not, since there’s no information in the medians about how far the other elements in the subsets deviate from the medians. For instance, for $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{4,5,6\}$ and $\{7,8,9\}$ the medians are $2$, $5$ and $8$ and the overall median is $5$, whereas for $\{1,2,9\}$, $\{4,5,9\}$ and $\{7,8,9\}$, the individual medians are the same but the overall median is $7$.

Comment: I see your point. So apparently, if the whole set is sorted beforehand the global median would be the median of all subsets? Am I right?

Comment: @Galuoises: No, that's only if the sets are all the same size, as in my example. In your question the sizes are indexed, so I presume they can be different. Then for $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{4,5,6\}$ and $\{7,8,9,10,11\}$ the overall median is $6$ but the median of the individual medians $2,5,9$ is $5$.